# What is the term for a matrix whose columns are orthogonal?

Tags: matrices, terminology, orthogonal-matrices

What is the term for a matrix whose columns are mutually orthogonal, but not necessarily othonormal?

I can't name such a matrix "orthogonal" because that would imply that all columns are unit vectors. By the way, why don't we name these matrices "orthonormal" instead of "orthogonal"? But that fight is over, I guess.

In other words, what is the term for a matrix $A$ for which $A^TA$ is a diagonal matrix, but not necessarily $I$?

One famous example are [Hadamard matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_matrix). I'd like to have a shorter term than "matrix whose rows are mutually orthogonal".

For my purpose it would be sufficient to have such a term for square matrices, but I'm also interested in a more general term that also covers non-square matrices.

Comment: I guess you've seen [this discussion](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/165609/)

Comment: So it is a matrix of the forma $OD$, with $D$ diagonal and $O$ orthogonal --in the need of a better name you may name it an "OD matrix", which at least is short and self-explanatory

Comment: @PietroMajer This would be a great answer, no need to hide it in the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it is a matrix of the form $OD$, with $D$ diagonal and $O$ orthogonal, in the need of a better term you may name it an "OD matrix", which at least is short and self-explanatory.

*Rmk:* Curiously, OD matrices already exist, in Transportation Planning, where $OD$ stands for "Origin\Destination."

Comment: Maybe we could name it "ortho-diag matrix" which is less ambiguous than "OD matrix".

Comment: But maybe these topics are far enough from each other, so that there be no risk of ambiguity